# In Android Studio, java file showing different icon with error

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Till yesterday Android Studio was working fine, but from today evening when I open error came that unable to load project file. I have cleared the cache and restarted the Android Studio, but now the java file icon is showing different as reverse L instead of C. And the code which I have written is also not reflecting instead of that some other code is reflecting.

Please find attached screenshot with error marked with circile. Kindly suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got the solution for this problem. Deleted the folder from C:\Users\AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches and issue resolved. Thanks to google.